# Scan and format IP address from user input in C

Tags: c, ip

I want to write a little script for faster startup another program and also because I always mismatch the startup syntax. I have written the following script in C - I think i must not explain it. its just a few scans for the input and startup the script.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

char *RHOST[256];
char *ROUTER[256];

printf("Bitte IP des Router eingeben: ");
scanf("%s",&ROUTER);

printf("Bitte IP des Opfers eingeben: ");
scanf("%s",&RHOST);

//printf("Du willst über den Router %s die Pakete von %s spoofen?\n",ROUTER,RHOST);

system("gnome-terminal -x sh -c \"mitmf --spoof --arp -i wlan0 --target %s --gateway %s --inject --html-payload \"any useful stuff\"; cat\"", RHOST, ROUTER);

}
```

The problem is, when I want to start the script I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mitmf.py", line 113, in <module>
    p.initialize(args)
  File "/usr/share/mitmf/plugins/Spoof.py", line 65, in initialize
    self.routermac = getmacbyip(self.gateway)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 53, in getmacbyip
    tmp = map(ord, inet_aton(ip))
socket.error: illegal IP address string passed to inet_aton
```

I guess, I haven't formatted the ip address input correct, please can you show me how to do so? Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you call it? what ip?

Comment: 1) C is not a "scripting" language. 2) What is the problem with a shell **script**? Why take a sledgehammer to crack a nut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have `RHOST` and `ROUTER` declared are as arrays of pointers to `char`, not arrays of `char` which is probably what you want.   They should instead be declared like this:

```
char RHOST[256];
char ROUTER[256];
```

And when calling `scanf`, the `%s` format string expects a `char *` or `char` array:

```
scanf("%s",ROUTER);
```

Also, the `system` function only takes a single parameter.  It doesn't do `printf` style substitutions.  You should first assemble the command in a separate string using `snprintf`, then pass that string to `system`.

```
char command[1000];
snprintf(command, 1000, "gnome-terminal -x sh -c \"mitmf --spoof --arp -i wlan0 --target %s --gateway %s --inject --html-payload \"any useful stuff\"; cat\"", RHOST, ROUTER);
system(command);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made RHOST and ROUTER array of strings. Make them array of char. Note that you must not input more than 255 characters.
Also system takes a string as argument, you give 3 arguments. The last 2 will be ignored. You will have do one of two things. Either concat parts of the string in system() with RHOST and ROUTER or sprintf RHOST and ROUTER into string from system() and use it for the system() call.